# Half duplex to full duplex LVDS

Tags: lvds

Suppose I have a half-duplex LVDS source that I want to interface with a full-duplex LVDS device operating in a half-duplex capacity (i.e. the full-duplex device has both a TX and an RX interface, but they don't operate simultaneously)

- The half-duplex source goes hi-Z when it is receiving.
- It drives its outputs when it's transmitting.

Just tying the TX and RX pairs together seems like a bad idea--the output driver on the half-duplex device would fight the output driver on the full-duplex device (unless the full-duplex device output driver goes high-impedance when there's no data).

Should I use some combination of a MUX and a selector? My switching logic would have to determine whether the output of the half-duplex device is high-impedance or not.

Here's an example schematic:
[image: Schematic]

Comment: Hmm those bonus points award may come back to bite you. Read the rules about shopping questions.

Comment: Whoops! I didn't mean "points" literally. I'll edit my question. Thanks.

Comment: I strongly suspect it's a bit more complicated than that on the USB side. USB is not 'straight' differential signalling - the SE0 (Single-Ended-Zero) condition is also used when both D+ & D- lines are pulled low simultaneously. That press release mentions "Icron’s ExtremeUSB® technology" and this is probably where the magic happens.

Comment: correct... there is a USB 2 Host polling slave response protocol that must be bundled into the serial payload

Comment: @brhans - you're right. I didn't read the press release well enough. Essentially, they're talking about using ExtremeUSB (USB to UTP) along with the EQCO850SC. I agree that USB is not always strictly differential. I was hoping the EQCO850SC had the magic to solve this, but I think it's the Extreme USB product that's doing it instead. I'll edit my question so it's non-USB and non-product specific--a far cry from the original question I asked you guys--sorry about that.